# Is Safari 8 clearing out my cookies every time it quits?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, safari

So for a client I'm having a subscribe lightbox pop up on first time load of a site.

I'm doing this by setting a cookie with [jquery.cookie.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/). Like so:

```
if (typeof $.cookie('subscription-has-popped-up') === 'undefined'){
    // No cookie, show the subscribe form.
    $('#subscribe').fadeIn();       
    $.cookie('subscription-has-popped-up', 'true');     
} else {
    // Has cookie, do nothing.
}
```

I've noticed a bug in Safari 8, when I quit out of Safari on my Mac, and reopen it, the lightbox pops up again. Is Safari clearing out my cookies every time I relaunch the application?

When I don't quit, of course on page reload I don't get the subscribe popup. It seems like quitting Safari and reopening is clearing the cookies.

Any insight to this issue?

If Safari does clear cookies every time the application quits by default, what would be a better way to go about fixing my problem so the user doesn't see the popup all the time?

Maybe there is a better way with PHP?

**EDIT: SOLUTION BELOW**

Answer (score 1):

This was my issue:

```
$.cookie('subscription-has-popped-up', 'true');
```

Needs to be:

```
$.cookie('subscription-has-popped-up', 'true', { expires: 365 });
```

Apparently without the expires attribute, [it's only a session cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#expires) and expires when the session ends. Changed it to that and all good.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **`typeof`** from the if statement.If the error still exist then check it on diffrent browser and report back...